Is there anything that stops the majority shareholder(s) from destroying company value?
Let's say Alice and Bob start a company. Alice owns 90% of said company, and Bob the remaining 10%. One day Alice decides to start destroying shareholder value, viz. by throwing all the company's expensive equipment into the trash. Can Bob do anything to stop her, or does Alice have overriding powers since she owns 90% of the company? Phased alternatively, I'm wondering what Alice's 90% voting share actually means. Can she simply outvote Bob on everything related to the company, even if it's patently nonsensical like the above?
I have no specific jurisdiction in mind.

A shareholder has no right to deal with any company property
Only directors and persons authorised by the directors can do that. And they are under a fiduciary duty to deal with the company’s assets in the best interests of all the shareholders.
So, throwing equipment in the skip is only justified if the cost of converting it to cash is less than the equipment is worth. Like if it’s a fax machine.

I think this answer could be improved with a jurisdiction tag. In my jurisdiction (UK) for example, this answer would be wrong for several reasons. Shareholders can: (a) deal with company property directly via resolutions, (b) authorise persons (including themselves) via resolutions to deal with company property, (c) (re)-write the company constitution to grant themselves an inherent right to deal with company property, (d) appoint themselves as directors, (e) pass resolutions to ratify acts of directors which are a breach of duty.

@DanielHatton The only one requiring a special resolution (or greater) is amendment of articles. The Companies Act 2006 leaves most matters to the articles, or provides sensible defaults in the absence of a rule in the articles. Also, it isn't % of share ownership which matters, but control of voting rights. E.g. you can own 51% of shares but control 100% of voting rights. Shares can also have differing voting rights for specific issues e.g. 1% of shares could control 100% of articles-amendment votes but 1% of other voting rights. Caveat: different rules apply to public vs private companies.

canada
Minority shareholders can apply to court for an "oppression remedy" when the company acts in a manner that is unfairly prejudicial to minority shareholders.
Alternatively, a shareholder can initiate a derivative action on behalf of the corporation itself.

By the way, the particular act in your question cannot be taken by a shareholder qua shareholder. Shareholders can vote, and thereby can make resolutions that order the company to do certain things. But the actual doing has to be by the hands of the directors or delegates.
Your example is that "One day Alice decides to start destroying shareholder value, viz. by throwing all the company's expensive equipment into the trash." That is not an act available to a mere shareholder (unless they themselves are also a director). If this was done by a mere shareholder, the company could sue that shareholder for conversion/theft (in your hypothetical, by a derivative action).

I'm not sure about Canadian law specifically, but at least in my jurisdiction (UK), shareholders can do a lot more than just appoint themselves as directors. They can also issue resolutions by which they can order the company to do whatever they want including overriding any decision of a director. This effectively gives them more control than directors. Indeed, the UK legislation specifically refers to shareholders (among other people) as having control.

The majority rules in the U.S. are similar to those above. The exact source and nature of the remedy varies somewhat by state and by form of organization (e.g., LLC v. corporation v. partnership).

The majority of shareholders can vote in a slate of directors who can hire a CEO with a mandate to do things that reduce the value of the minority shareholders’ holdings.
That is why a venture capitalist investing in a startup negotiates a stock purchase agreement with the command the founders that had many provisions to insure they have protection from the majority.
For example if a VC invests 10 million dollars and gets 20% of the company they do not want the founders with 80% to decide to liquidate the company and distribute the resulting cash prorate to the shareholders.
